# Sequence 1, 3, 8, 18, 38, 78 from a recursive function

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function in Java that would display the n element in a mathematical number sequence (1 3 8 18 38 78).

This is what I've managed to do so far:

```
public static int recfunc(int i) {
    if(i==1) { return 1; }
    if(i==2) { return 2+recfunc(i-1); }
    if(i==3) { return 5+recfunc(i-1); }
    if(i>3) { return ((2^(i-3))*5)+recfunc(3); }
    return 0;
}
```

To calculate n(>3), you simply add together 2^(i-3) from each step(i>3) and then add 8 in the end. So, for the 6th element, you would have to do this calculation: 40 + 20 + 10 + 8 = 78.

The problem with the above code is that it successfully calculates the increase in a number between two n(s) and then ads 5 + 2 + 1 (8) to it, but it doesn't apply all the previous steps (20 + 10).

Update:

I'm getting somewhere, but it still doesn't do what it should.

```
public static int recfunc(int i, boolean param) {
    if(param==false) {
        if(i==1) { return 1; }
        if(i==2) { return 2+recfunc(i-1, false); }
        if(i==3) { return 5+recfunc(i-1, false); }
        if(i>3) { param = true; }
    }
    if(param==true) {
        if(i==4) {
            return ((2^(i-3))*5)+recfunc(i-1, false); }
        else {
            return ((2^(i-3))*5)+recfunc(i-1, true); }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your power function. ^ in java does not mean to raise to a power. It means XOR.

You can use java's Math.pow()

```
int recfunc(int i) {
    if(i==1) { return 1; }
    if(i==2) { return 2+recfunc(i-1); }
    if(i==3) { return 5+recfunc(i-1); }
    if(i>3) {
        return ((Math.pow(2,(i-3))*5)+recfunc(i-1));
 }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine now. Thanks for your help!

```
public static int recfunc(int i, boolean param) {
    if(param==false) {
        if(i==1) { return 1; }
        if(i==2) { return 2+recfunc(i-1, false); }
        if(i==3) { return 5+recfunc(i-1, false); }
        if(i>3) { param = true; }
    }
    if(param==true) {
        if(i==4) {
            return (int)Math.pow(2.0f,(double)(i-3))*5+(int)(recfunc(i-1, false)); }
        else {
            return (int)Math.pow(2.0f,(double)(i-3))*5+(int)(recfunc(i-1, true)); }
    }
    return 0;
}
```